# Extract Date from string ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have this string :

```
Rep. Barletta, Lou [R-PA-11] (Introduced 06/04/2015)
```

And I want to extract the date which is "06/04/2015". How do i do this in ruby?
I have tried to do something like this:

```
str[-1..-11]
```

but didnt work. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Is it always the same name/format? I'd recommend using regular expressions to match this.

Comment: @Piccolo yeah, it is always the same format..how do i use regular expression for this? Im not used to it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "Rep. Barletta, Lou [R-PA-11] (Introduced 06/04/2015)"
str.match(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/)[0]
#=> "06/04/2015"
```

This code matches anything that's in the format of 2 numbers/2 numbers/4 numbers and returns it.

If there's a possibility of having XX/XX/XXXX somewhere else in the string, I'd probably use the following code instead:

```
str = "Rep. Barletta, Lou [R-PA-11] (Introduced 06/04/2015)"
str.match(\(Introduced (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\)$)[0]
#=> "06/04/2015"
```

This searches for `(Introduced XX/XX/XXXX)` and grabs the date from that in particular.

Comment: Thanks! You have saved my life :)

Comment: Suppose `str #=>  "Rep. Barletta, Lou [R-PA-11] 99/99/9999 (Introduced 06/04/2015)"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The OP said that it was in the same format each time

Comment: I believe the OP meant the date format was the same each time: "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Could be, in that case I'd probably use the pattern ``\(Introduced \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\)$`` and then use substrings to get the date from that.

Comment: Oh wait substrings are dumb for that, I could just use a capture group. Edited in, thanks @CarySwoveland

Comment: Posslbly without "Introduced" or `$`. (Only the OP knows.) You could also write `str[/\(Introduced (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\)/,1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Date has a parse method, which happens to just work.

```
require 'date'

str = "Rep. Barletta, Lou [R-PA-11] (Introduced 06/04/2015)"
p d = Date.parse(str) # => #<Date: 2015-04-06 ((2457119j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

str[-11..-2] if the position of the date does not change

Comment: Quite possibly the best answer. The OP was almost there. `str[-11,10]` also works. (Edit to put backticks around str[-11..-2] to make it appear like this: `str[-11..-2]`).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Piccolo's comment. Here is a simple regular expression you can try in irb. I recommend experimenting in irb to learn some rudimentary [Ruby regular expressions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html).

For example, `/.+([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}).+/` looks for anything followed by two digits, slash, two digits, slash, four digits, then anything:

```
$ irb
2.2.0 :001 > s='Rep. Barletta, Lou [R-PA-11] (Introduced 06/04/2015)'
2.2.0 :009 > /.+([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}).+/ =~ s && $1
 => "06/04/2015" 
2.2.0 :010 >
```

Comment: This has the same weakness as Picollo's answer.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland hence the need to experiment. I wrote, "then anything" -- I should have been more explicit, "... including another date (which would be ignored)".

Answer (score 0):

@steenslag's answer looks for valid dates (unlike the other answers), but could still be tripped up:

```
str = "The first 10 may go 15/15/2015 with Lou (Introduced 06/04/2015)"
Date.parse(str)
  #=> #<Date: 2015-05-10 ((2457153j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

To ensure the date is in the specified format, you could do the following:

```
require 'date'

def extract_date(str, fmt)
  a = str.each_char
         .each_cons(10)
         .find { |a| Date.strptime(a.join, fmt) rescue nil }
  a ? a.join : nil
end
```

For `str` as above:

```
extract_date(str, '%d/%m/%Y')
  #=> "06/04/2015"
```

A second example:

```
extract_date("15/15/2015", '%d/%m/%Y')
  #=> nil
```